# How to use SPFx PNPSPJS on local workbench?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp

I'm new to spfx and I am making a react web app in spfx. I have this so far to log in using the current context

```
  sp.setup({
    spfxContext: this.context
  });
```

but if I am testing locally on the workbench, but want to read from a list on my tenant, how can I change it to log in there instead? Is there any article/tutorial for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your local web server (as if you were going to use the local workbench) using `gulp serve`, but use the `--nobrowser` flag to prevent it from automatically opening a browser window to your local workbench, you can then open the SharePoint hosted workbench on your tenant and add your web part there, which will then run in the context of your tenant and give you access to data on that site.

Again, locally run

```
gulp serve --nobrowser
```

and then in a browser open

```
https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/your-site/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx
```

and then just add your web part to the workbench as you would normally do, and you will have access to all the lists/libraries on `/your-site/`.

Here is a link to the documentation in the SPFx HelloWorld web part tutorial describing how to [preview the web part in SharePoint's hosted workbench](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part#preview-the-web-part-in-sharepoints-hosted-workbench).

Comment: I am getting "Your web part will not appear in the toolbox. Please make sure "gulp serve" is running in a web part project. Please refresh the page once "gulp serve" is running."

Comment: Did you run `gulp serve` before opening the browser to the workbench on your tenant?

Comment: Yes. But i think it is a trust cert issue. I already did the trust the dev cert, but I had to go into dev tools, open some manifest.json file in a new tab, and click proceed anyways, and ten refresh the page and it worked.